# Java simpleDateFormat conversion

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

trying to perform date comparison however:

`date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH").parse("12-03-25 02")` is equal to

`date2=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH").parse("12-03-25 03")`

What is the problem? Taking `date1.getHour` i get `3`.

Ideas are welcome

Comment: I get `2` for `date1.getHours()`.  There must be some other code that is affecting your result.

Comment: cannot reproduce on JDK 6, show the actual program?

Comment: I am also getting 2 in jdk 7

Comment: Could there be a copy-paste issue? With two "date2" and no "date1"?

Comment: deleted my answer, as it wasnt really answering anything.  On jdk6  I also get 2. Are you sure you're not getting hours on date2 instead?

Comment: http://prohost.lt/stack/datefail.png, tested jdk6 and jdk7

Answer (score 4):

The 25th of March 2012 is the day where daylight saving time switch is done is many countries, typically at 2 o'clock. So 2AM and 3AM are the same time this day, in your locale. That's why you're seeing this.

Comment: How to deal with such problem then? (checked with my country, its march 25)

Comment: Good catch.  To everyone else: you can confirm this by invoking `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));` before constructing the `SimpleDateFormat`s.

Comment: It's not a problem. The result is correct. 2AM and 3AM represent the same moment, so printing 2 or 3 doesn't matter.

Comment: @JB Nizet not really, consider you have logging done at 2 and 3...what would it be then?

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same hour. That day, at 2 o'clock, it's already 3 o'clock. There is 0 millisecond between 2 o'clock and 3 o'clock. There would be a problem in October, when at 3, it's 2 once again. If that's important, consider using an unambiguous format, like a timestamp, instead of wall-clock time.

Comment: @JB Nizet So if you have a log at 2, and it is different from hour 3. As far as i would guess, logging is not affected by this saving, therefore in my case other logging values are different and i can't just skip them